# Interface Builder : cannot assign custom class to table view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, controller, interface-builder

I am trying to create a simple app for iOS that uses a tab bar controller to present either a map view or a table view. Both the map view and the table view have the same navigation bar button items:

A Logout button on the left, and Refresh, Add New buttons on the right side of the navigation bar. So I have started experimenting the idea of having a parent controller called **LocationViewController**, which inherits from the **UIViewController**.

For the table view, I have a controller called `TableViewController: LocationViewController`, and another controller called `MapViewController: LocationViewController`.

On the storyboard, I added a set of two buttons (for refresh and add new) to the top header section of each view (very small, may be hard to see). See the image attached below:

[image: MapView]

[image: TableView]

There is no problem for me to assign the custom view controller **MapViewController** to my map view panel, but I cannot find the custom controller class **TableViewController** in the panel (see the below screenshot)

[image: custom table view controller class not found]

I found a similar post on stackoverflow, and a reboot solved that problem, which I also tried, but did not solve my problem at all.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You have added youe buttons in the wrong place. I do not know the right name for the bar, but it contains "associated objects". What you want to achieve should look something like this :
[image]
Unfortunatelly, you cannot add two `UIBarButtonItems` to one side of navigation bar via interface builder. You can either drag a `UIView` instead of `UIBarButtonItem` to that "slot" and add two `UIButtons` there, or you ca add multiple buttons from code.</strike>

---

Also, it seems that the name of your question is a bit misleading :) After carefull reread of your post I found the "right" question.

Answer - you have added a `UITableViewController` in your storyboard, but your class doesn't inherit from `UITableViewController`. If you want to keep the base class, you will have to make it a "plain" `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` to it. Note, that this way you won't be able to have prototype cells.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to subclass it from UITableViewController. Replace the UIViewController parent class for UITableViewController, like this:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
```

Then make sure you selected the View Controller where blue color is all around it and then you can place the name of the class that inherits from UITableViewController.